# Stream Onvif using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, onvif

I've written a cpp code, based on the Onvif example code:

> https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-onvif-backchannel.c

I have managed to stream and a regular RTSP stream but when I try to read it with onvif client it just work, and say the stream is not Onvif compatible.
What do I wrong?
My gst version is 1.14.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to upgrade the gstreamer library in your board/PC to allow for onvif... the best is to upgrade to 1.18 or even yet 1.20. They would have support for onvif replay and backchannel which is not standard rtsp

otherwise you may want to try to write and extend the library for the features you need